# PASCAL: Looping through an array to create folders?

Tags: arrays, delphi, loops, pascal

So I am creating a pascal script that will create a directory within a main directory and ALSO create multiple folders inside of that new directory. (Insert XZibit pun)

Now the way we do this where I work, we send these variables to an exe that will then create directories based on what is being passed (in this case, path 'fullpath').

I am not sure if I am approaching this correctly and would love the much more prominent PASCAL guru's input :)

```
const
ARRAY1: Array[1..9] of String = (
     'NQN', 'Documents', 'Correspondences',
     'Worksheets', 'Reports', 'Claims',
     'Certificate of Insurance', 'Invoice', 'Monthly Reports'
);
var
i: Integer;
fullpath, path, name, os, es, cmd: String;
Code : LongWord;
res: Integer;

Begin
path := 'Policies'
fullpath := path+'\'+[i]
     for i := 1 to 9 do
    IF(ReqList.Values['sRM_ID'] = '') then
        Begin
            cmd := 'C:\XXX\bin\mkdir.exe "'+fullpath+'"';
            res :=ExecuteProc(cmd, 'C:\XXX\bin', true, -1, true, nil, os, es, code);
            if(res = 0) then
                Begin
                    ReqList.values['NoErrors'] := '1';
                    ReqList.Values['Response_content']:=  '{"valid":"1","message":"'+ReplaceString(ReplaceString(os,#13,'',false),#10,'',false)+'"}';
                end
            else
                begin
                    ReqList.Values['NoErrors'] := '0';
                    Reqlist.Values['Response_Content'] := '{"valid":"0","message":"'+ReplaceString(ReplaceString(os,#13,'',false),#10,'',false)+'"}';
                end;
        END
        ELSE
                Begin
                    ReqList.Values['Response_Content'] := '{"valid":"0","message":"A folder or file with the same name already exists."}';
                End;
                    ReqList.Values['Response_ContentType'] := 'HTML';
```

Comment: Take a look on [ForceDirectories](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_ForceDirectories.html) and use *real* (complete) fullpathes.

Comment: Would make more sense to use a scripting language for scripting tasks

Comment: The exe takes it's predetermined directory and then takes the path being supplied to have a destination for these folders as a basis.

I am going to keep that tab up for ForceDirectories, because that seems pretty useful.

Comment: I would also use IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter...in case you move the code to different OS...It will check to make sure the path supplied has a path delimiter and if not it will add it...  fullpath := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(path)+[i]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you identify the absolute path for each entry in your array, ForceDirectories will create them if they don't already exist, as bummi suggested above.

Assuming your root path is relative to the current executable path, it could be as simple as this:

```
const
  ARRAY1: Array [1 .. 9] of String = ('NQN', 'Documents', 'Correspondences',
    'Worksheets', 'Reports', 'Claims', 'Certificate of Insurance', 'Invoice',
    'Monthly Reports');
var
  s: string;
  path: string;
  fullpath: string;
begin
  path := 'Policies';
  for s in ARRAY1 do
  begin
    fullpath := ExpandFileName(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(path) + s);
    ForceDirectories(fullpath);
  end;
end;
```